Having trouble while building apk for my app made in Kivy and Python, using Action on GitHub
I am trying to use Action on GitHub to convert my application made using Kivy into apk but facing same issue every time.
Can someone please help me. Following is the error message I am getting every time.
[WARNING]: ERROR: /github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!
# Command failed: ['/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=induperator', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3crystax==3.6,kivy,python', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
Following is the excerpt from the buildozer.spec file.
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3crystax==3.6,kivy,python

I have tried multiple permutations and combinations on the above said "#requirements == ..." part.
Also tried build.yml from various sources including using this one given on stackoverflow.
How do I create an apk file from kivy with github
It is running till about 20,000 lines then giving this error.
Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this?
Been stuck at the same place for a week.
Thanks in advance.

Does your build work locally when you're not using GitHub Actions? Can you provide the full error/traceback or log output?

I have downloaded the log file. But it contains too many lines. So, it would be better if I share it as an attachment. Or you can look at this using the following link https://github.com/makhrakhatu/firstapk/actions/runs/8668297322/job/23773399856.  I can add you to the repository. Thanks for the reply.
